# gulp - how to push (or commit) each build

Tags: git, gulp

I have a `gulpfile.js` and I want to upload my build files to my repo each time I build the project.

When the build gets uploaded or committed, I wish for the description to be like: `Build (#999)`

Example: https://github.com/elementary/mvp

How could I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-git) (gulp-git)

This can help you to perform all `git` functions.